# Prove the set of continuous real-valued functions on the interval $[0,1]$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{[0,1]}$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, vector-spaces, proof-writing

> Prove the set of continuous real-valued functions on the interval $[0,1]$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{[0,1]}$

*My Attempted Proof*:

$$\mathbb{R}^{[0,1]} := \{ f \  | \  f : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}\}$$

**Part 1** :Take $f_0 : [0,1] \to 0$ (i.e. $f_o(x) = 0 \ \ \  \forall x \in [0,1]$). Clearly $f_0 \in \mathbb{R}^{[0,1]}$, and thus we have our additive identity for $\mathbb{R}^{[0,1]}$.

**Part 2** : Now take $\alpha : [0,1] \to a \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\beta : [0,1] \to b \in \mathbb{R}$. Fix $x \in [0,1]$, then

$$\alpha(x) + \beta(x) : (x \in [0,1] \to a \in \mathbb{R}) + (x \in [0,1] \to b \in \mathbb{R})$$

which is the same as $x \in [0,1] \to (a \in \mathbb{R} + b \in \mathbb{R}) = (a+b) \in \mathbb{R}$, and thus $$\alpha(x) + \beta(x) \in \mathbb{R}^{[0,1]}$$

and $\mathbb{R}^{[0,1]}$ is closed under addition.

**Part 3** :Finally we take $\gamma \in [0,1]$ and $f \in \mathbb{R}^{[0,1]}$. $f(x) = a \in \mathbb{R}$ for some $x \in [0,1]$, then $$\gamma \cdot f(x) = \gamma \cdot a \in \mathbb{R}$$

and $\mathbb{R}^{[0,1]}$ is closed under scalar multiplication. $\square$

---

Is my proof correct and logical/rigorous?

Comment: You have tried to prove that $\mathbb{R}^{[0,1]}$  is an $\mathbb{R}-$linear space, although your proof is not correct as you are considering only constant functions, but not the task at hand.

Comment: Not correct as b00n heT said. In fact you nowhere even mention continuity in your proof, that should be alarming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to emphasize the continuity. That is, you need to show that the set of continuous functions is nonempty and that it is closed under the operations of $\mathbb{R}^{[0,1]}$.

When you take the zero function, you need to note that this function is in fact continuous. Similarly with addition, you need to take two **continuous functions** $f$ and $g$ and show that $f+g$ is continuous.

Also, in the end you should take an arbitrary $a\in\mathbb{R}$ and prove that $(a\cdot f)\colon [0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous for all $f\colon [0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ continuos, where $(a\cdot f)(x):=a\cdot f(x)$ for all $x\in [0,1]$.